# able to scroll past html content into white background

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: "Mona Sans";
  background: var(--color-bg);
  display: grid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

html {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: "Mona Sans";
}
```

Not sure how to change this color to match the background, this only happens on my macbook and not my windows pc.

[video of what i'm describing](https://streamable.com/yx304r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is actually to do with the [`theme-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color)  meta tag

Example:
`meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4" />`

Here's an excerpt from the `index.html` file I use on my portfolio site:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Meta tags for Colou Schemes -->
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <meta
      name="theme-color"
      content="#FFFFFF"
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"
    />
    <meta
      name="theme-color"
      content="#000000"
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
    />
  </head>
...
```